# Commutator in a normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $a,b\in G$ and $N \triangleleft G$.

If $aba^{-1}b^{-1}\in N$, what other commutators are elements of $N$? In particular, if $G=\langle a,b \rangle$, does this imply that all commutators in $G$ are elements of $N$? I've tried exploring various conjugates of $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$, but have yet to stumble upon any that are illuminating.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If $[a,b]\in N$, $G=\langle a,b\rangle$, and $N\unlhd G$, then $[G,G]\le N$:

1. The quotient group $Q=G/N$ is generated by the cosets $aN$ and $bN$.
2. Because $aba^{-1}b^{-1}\in N$, the cosets $aN$ and $bN$ commute in $Q$.
3. Obviously $aN$ commutes with itself as does $bN$, so $Q$ is abelian.
4. Whenever $G/N$ is abelian we can infer that $[G,G]\le N$.

Comment: What about in the case where $G\neq\langle a,b\rangle$? Is there a way to determine what other commutators are in $N$?

Answer (score 1):

Let's write $[a,b]$ for $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$. Note that for any $g$ in $G$, $$[gag^{-1},gbg^{-1}]=gag^{-1}gbg^{-1}ga^{-1}g^{-1}gb^{-1}g^{-1}=gaba^{-1}b^{-1}g^{-1}=g[a,b]g^{-1};$$ in words, this says a conjugate of a commutator is the commutator of the conjugates. Thus, if $[a,b]$ is in the normal subgroup $N$, then so is $[x,y]$, where $x=gag^{-1}$ and $y=gbg^{-1}$ for arbitrary $g$ in $G$.